# How do I change a label's font (and font size)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Almost all of the sources I've seen while searching are outdated for such a simple question. How can I change a label's font and size in pyqt4?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need `QFont` (in `setupUi` method or anywhere):

```
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("FreeMono"))
font.setBold(True)
self.someLabel.setFont(font)
```

You can also check [QFont](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfont.html) reference.

P.S. `_fromUtf8` is `QtCore.QString.fromUtf8` imported as `_fromUtf8`

Comment: so you're basically saying we can't change font midway when program already started? (dynamically)